# Adyen web component v5.31.3, Paynow payment method is not working

Tags: web-component, adyen

Hi Using Adyen web component v5.31.3, we are trying to implement Paynow payment method.
Followed steps mentioned in https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/paynow/web-component/ here

1. Session API creation.
2. Using Session data created AdyenCheckout instance
3. checkout.create('paynow').mount('#paynow-container')
4. Payment method is enabled in Adyen portal
   No error in console . We are unable to get the paynow payment option. Can someone help on this ? If Something i am missing ?
5. Created Adyen web using Embed script and stylesheet
6. Created Adyen component v5.31.3 followed steps mentioned here https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/?platform=Web&integration=Components
7. Created paynow-container dom element.https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/paynow/web-component/
8. Created instance of AdyenCheckout , and run code **checkout.create('paynow').mount('#paynow-container');**
9. No error in console or browser but still unable to view paynow option.
10. paynow option is enabled in Adyen.

Comment: Contact Adyen. You are basically saying _my BMW does not drive, what should I do_

Answer (score 1):

The steps are correct, including the application and component setup, however PayNow must be enabled as payment method available to the shoppers.
This is not self-service but must be [requested](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/paynow/web-drop-in/)

> Contact our Support Team to enable PayNow.